# React component listen to grand-children events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am working on a component library which includes `ButtonBar` and `Button` components.

The `ButtonBar` component takes as `children` some `Button`s and then renders them in a nice layout.

So, the consuming code, in the most basic case, would look something like this:

```
<ButtonBar>
  <Button>First Button</Button>
  <Button>Second Button</Button>
  <Button>Third Button</Button>
</ButtonBar>
```

One feature of `ButtonBar` is keeping track of the last clicked `Button` and giving it special styling.

To accomplish this, `ButtonBar` has code like this:

```
updateToggle(child) {
  // update state based on child...
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.children = React.Children.map(this.children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      press: () => {
        child.props.press();
        this.updateToggle(child);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

This code is trying to tap into the `Button`'s `press` event (which is called by `Button` on itself when it's clicked upon) and then calls `ButtonBar`'s `updateToggle` function.

This is sort of like "extending" Button's press function.

Anyway, this pattern breaks down when the user does something like this:

```
<ButtonBar>
  <Link to="/"><Button>First Button</Button></Link>
  <Link to="/foo"><Button>Second Button</Button></Link>
  <Link to="/bar"><Button>Third Button</Button></Link>
</ButtonBar>
```

Now that the direct child of `ButtonBar` is not a Button type, we don't have an easy way determine if a custom event happened on the `Button`.

Is there a different way `ButtonBar` should be interacting with it's `children`?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding Link as a property of Button?

```
<ButtonBar>
  <Button to='/'>First Button</Button>
  <Button to="/foo">Second Button</Button>
  <Button to="/bar>Third Button</Button>
</ButtonBar>
```

You could enforce that only Button's are passed as Childen to ButtonBar

```
{React.Children.map( this.props.children, (child, i) => { 
            if (child.type.name === Button.name)
                    React.cloneElement(child, {
                press: () => {
                  child.props.press();
                  this.updateToggle(child);
                }
              })
        })}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I feel this could be a good specific solution to the problem, but I guess I was looking for a more generic answer (but I may not be approaching the problem correctly)

Comment: you can pass props from component to grandchildren only if 'children component' explicitely passes props to it its children (component's grandchildren). You can use React Context for limited use cases. See https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html